# How to include multiple products with diffrent mode in stripe?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, checkout, subscription

I want a stripe checkout page for subscription but now I want to use same checkout page for subscription mode and payment mode.
suppose my subscription is for $99, and user selects $10 as top-up or add-on then I want to add that money also as payment not as subscription, how can I acheive this ?
my code for stripe checkout session for subscription is as below.

```
        sessionObj = {
            mode: "subscription",
            line_items: [
                {
                    price: priceId,
                    quantity: 1,
                }
            ],
            subscription_data: {
                metadata
            },
            metadata,
            success_url: `${Meteor.settings.private.PUBLIC_SITE_URL}/contact-us`,
            cancel_url: `${Meteor.settings.private.PUBLIC_SITE_URL}/payment-failure`,
            payment_method_types: ["card"]
        }
        const stripeRes = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(sessionObj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine recurring and non-recurring price with Checkout Sessions in `subscription` mode. For example you could do this:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: "subscription",
    line_items: [
        { price: 'price_aaa', quantity: 1 }, // $99 monthly recurring payment
        { price: 'price_bbb', quantity: 1 }, // $10 on time payment
    ],
    success_url: 'http://www.example.com',
    cancel_url: 'http://www.example.com',
});
```

Here the customer will be charged $109 ($99 + $10) the first month, and then $99 for the following months.

Comment: can I use static price ? or I need to create price on stripe ?

Comment: You can either use [`line_items.price`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price) with an existing price ID (see example above) or use [`line_items.price.data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data) to directly set the amount/currency/etc.